# How can I include more than one path on a custom docletpath?

Tags: java, javadoc

I have a javadoc doclet that requires an additional jar file to be on the doclet's classpath.  To run the doclet from the command line, I do something like this:

```
java com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main -doclet myPackage.myDoclet -docletpath /path/to/doclet/classes
```

When I run that, it finds the doclet on the path and executes it, but the doclet uses an additional jar that needs to be on the classpath, so eventually, I get a ClassNotFoundException.

When I change the command line to this:

```
java com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main -doclet myPackage.myDoclet -docletpath /path/to/doclet/classes:/path/to/some.jar
```

It no longer finds the doclet (`javadoc: error - Cannot find doclet class com.adventact.si.workflow.javadoc.ListClass`).  So, it appears that the doclet argument does not accept a list of paths, but only a single one.

(note that these command lines aren't complete - I'm not showing how I set the classpath, as it's irrelevant to the docletpath problem, and is really spammy.)

How do you workaround this?

Comment: What OS are you running this on?

Comment: Windows.  You nailed the : vs. ; in your answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation for Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#docletpath) says that a list of paths is allowed.  Ensure that you're using the correct path-separating character, either ';' or ':' depending on whether you're on Windows or UNIX (respectively).

NOTE:  If you're truly using `java` and not `javadoc` to execute your doclet, then check the implementation of your class.  `-docletpath` is not a standard option to the `java` executable, so must be being interpreted by your doclet implementation.  However, if you're using `javadoc` then the documentation I pointed to above says:

> If *classpathlist* contains multiple paths or jar files, they should be separated
>   with a colon (`:`) on Solaris and a semi-colon (`;`) on Windows.

Comment: Editted OP to more completely reflect the fact that I am indeed calling java and not javadoc.